# MySQL Remove All Text from Field EXCEPT Pattern

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm working on a WordPress database, and I need some help cleaning up the post_content field.

There are about 5,000 posts that contain something like this:
`RANDOM JUNK<img src="http://domain.tld/randomString.jpg" />MORE RANDOM JUNK`

or

`RANDOM JUNK<img src="http://domain.tld/randomString.png" />MORE RANDOM JUNK`

or

`RANDOM JUNK<img src="https://domain.tld/randomString.jpg" />MORE RANDOM JUNK`

or

`RANDOM JUNK<img src="https://domain.tld/randomString.png" />MORE RANDOM JUNK`

I need to delete everything except the image, and there might be other HTML tags in some of the fields.

Where should a SQL beginner start?

Comment: which backend language do you use?

Comment: I've added an answer that shows that this is possible using just MySQL, assuming that's your DB.  I used it on my wordpress blog to remove and expand all [gallery] tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible with sql. sql could just find a regexp and tell its there, but not capture a part of it and insert it again.

You need to query all images first then match your adresses then insert it again...

```
$sql = "SELECT postid, image FROM posts";
$result = mysql_query($sql) OR die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    preg_match('/<img[^>]+>/i', $row['image'], $matches);
    $sql = "UPDATE posts SET image = '".$matches[0]."'
            WHERE postid = ".$row['postid'];
    mysql_query($sq) OR die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: I thought that might be the case. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, assuming the 'img' tag you want to keep is somewhat unique.  Use SUBSTRING_INDEX

```
update posts set post_content = 
concat(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content,'<img src="http://domain.tld/',1) ,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content,'.jpg" />',-1) 
)
```

Keeps only the 'img' tag you want.